# Why did the question with "blue guy" get many views?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Yesterday a question was posted under [identification-request](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request). Some unregistered user posted a question about Shiva's family. He referred gods as people and Shiva as *blue guy*. It was just an identification request question. But the question got 5 upvotes and 1 downvote and **1103 views** since yesterday. One user commented "+1 for the blue guy".

Why do questions with good content and useful info not get views like that?

Comment: I even wonder why such questions get so many views. This question might have shown as [Hot Question](http://stackexchange.com/questions). BTW, who was the user commented "+1 for the blue guy"? I think less active or new users (whose rep above 100) might have upvoted that question.

Comment: It was there yesterday. I think he voluntarily removed his comment.  Any user with rep above 15 can vote up. The user was Chinmay Saurupia rep 30. I think the privileges should be edited after a discussion.

Comment: A moderator can remove a comment or change a low quality answer to a comment. I cannot remove a comment. May be he is a Shiva bhaktha and I don't have a problem with that. I think that one should be encouraged to know other less known facts and stories of gods which are there in other good questions too.

Comment: I think you are assuming Shiva devotees upvoted that question. That is wrong. Most probably that OP might be Non Indian or Non Hindu. He/She used unregistered account just to know names (OP guessed that question would be downvoted and he didn't register). Coming to your assumption, people here don't do this selective voting except 1 or 2 users. This site has more Advaitins or people who don't follow any particular school. They are also questions of other Gods which got many upvotes. May be upvotes were to encourage OP. Also, importantly **it got upvotes only after SV editing the question**.

Comment: Don't take me wrong. I didn't assume shiva devotees voted the question. sv and Keshav both modified the question. I am not against any particular school. I agree with your point of selective voting.

Comment: @SreeCharan One can't say y users upvote..if one finds that a  question is useful,informative he probably will..so u can assume that thus many users found that post as useful..so thus many users did not even know about Shiva's family before that..& if someone is a Shiva devotee he will probably have more reasons for downvoting the post(as opposed to upvoting) because there Bhagawan is mentioned just as a **guy**..

Comment: ...speaking about myself,i neither up nor down voted the post..also i think u are a practising hindu like me..then like urself i have also found many a times,very basic questions getting huge no of votes..those voters mite not be acquainted with the very basic aspects of Hinduism i guess..that is what i feel..so votes as such shud not be given undue importance here.

Comment: @Rickross I too neither upvoted nor downvoted the question. It was some other user who downvoted the question. Who is a practising hindu?

Comment: @SreePractising Hindu(PH) is the one who has Guru Diksha,does regular Japa,Pujas as taught by his Guru as mentioned in Scriptures....I don't think most users are like that on this board...So what may be a very common knowledge for a PH is a new or important info for most others..that's y they upvote such trivial posts..basically u never know y one upvotes..each user has his own reasons..

Comment: I upvoted just to encourage the user because it looked like an honest question from someone who doesn't know much about Hindu gods. Some users here assume they know all FAQs about Hinduism. But once in a while you get pleasantly surprised by seeing a question such as [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15200/2995) which you have no clue about and it's no different than the 'who's the blue guy' question but it only got 163 views. Maybe it needs a catchy title!

Comment: @sv.@SreeCharan i also felt the same,that the question has genuine intent..he simply wanted to know about those present in the picture..although his language not quite the best one may be..

Comment: When question have catchy title and get instant attention like editing, answers etc, it hits HNQ. But HNQ are unpredictable and bring more and more votes, comments and answers. Also remember HNQ also have positive effect too in bringing new people to site

Comment: @SreeCharan Yeah I upvoted that question because of the same reason posted by sv. I want to encourage that user, he was genuinely interested in Hinduism and even bought a picture of Bholenath.

Comment: @SreeCharan And I deleted my comment because I thought OP might feel that I am making fun of his language which was clearly not my intention.

Comment: It's fine. My intention is that other question with good content should get the same attention as this question.